# Jquery event handlers get on increasing in two consecutive click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

In this code it is creating additional alerts each time I click any option.I want only one alert each time I click the menu items

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu").click(function(){
        $("option").click(function(){
            alert(menu.value);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Well you have a click handler within a click handler...

Answer (score 5):

Don't nest event handlers. If one element is inside another, use a more specific selector:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu option").click(function(){
        alert(menu.value);
    });
});
```

Or neater yet:

```
$(document).on("click", "#menu option", function(){
    alert(menu.value);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: It worked for the select menu created inside body,but not working when select menu options are added dynamically from the database

Comment: Then you need to share your HTML and clarify better what your desired result is.

Comment: After runnning few tests I want to ask whether we can save the returned data,status from a jquery event handler function in a variable and use that variable later ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but it sounds like you should ask that as a separate question.